# jQuery switch classes on click

Tags: jquery

I have a WordPress site where I have some "pipe" elements which I want to change color when clicked. I'm new to jQuery so I would need some help to do this. This is what I have so far (a very simplified version of it all):

jQuery:

```
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery(".--clearGreen").click(function() {
    jQuery(this).addClass("--clearGreenClicked");
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
.--clearGreen {
 background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
 border: 2px solid green;
}

.--clearGreenClicked {
 background-color: blue;
 border: 2px solid blue;
 color: white;
}
```

This works to add the `.--clearGreenClicked` class to the clicked `.--clearGreen` "pipe" that I have on the page. What I would like to achieve is to make it so that only the clicked "pipe" gets the change applied to it and all the other "pipes" return to the original styling, so basically that they "switch" styles depending on what "pipe" is clicked. I've tried to use `.not` in combination with `.has` but I can't seem to get it to work properly. Thanks!

Comment: use toggle for class

Comment: can you post a fiddle ?

Comment: Your wording does not match your code.  "this works to add the class to *all* the pipes" - nope, it only does it to the one you clicked, which is then what you're asking.  If you can create an [mcve] (snippet) you might be able to explicitly demonstrate the issue to us.

Comment: @freedomn-m absolutely

Comment: @freedomn-m I think your answer meets what the OP wants ;)

Comment: Yepp should have formatted it better. But thanks all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As worded:

> only the clicked pipe gets the change and the other pipes [remain] with the original styling"

your code does exactly that, because you've used `$(this).addClass`.

So assuming you're asking "and the other pipes *return* to the original styling", so only one is "selected" at a time:

```
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery(".--clearGreen").click(function() {
    jQuery(".--clearGreenClicked").removeClass("--clearGreenClicked");
    jQuery(this).addClass("--clearGreenClicked");
  });
});
```

---

Additional:

You can use `.not` to reduce the changes made, eg:

```
jQuery(".--clearGreenClicked").not(this).removeClass("--clearGreenClicked");
jQuery(this).addClass("--clearGreenClicked");
```

which will stop the code from removing and then re-adding the class - this could make a difference if you have a `transition` on the css.

Comment: Hmm yeah, I should have formatted it better, but this fixes my issue. And it was this simple well I got some to learn, but many thanks for your answer!

Comment: Glad it helps.  It's not always easy to describe an issue and, especially in development, precise wording can make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function () {
        jQuery(".--clearGreen").click(function () {
            jQuery(this).toggleClass("--clearGreenClicked");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `toggleClass` function to remove class when it exist and add class if it doesn't exist. Like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function () {
        jQuery('.--clearGreen').click(function () {
            jQuery(this).toggleClass('--clearGreenClicked');
        });
    });
</script>
```