# Change class on each click

Tags: jquery, click

When we click on the span `referent-R` it has the `checked` class. This works.
However when we click another time on the same `span` I would like to remove the `checked` class. It should radio button/checkbox behavior.

```js
$('.referent-R').click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).removeClass('checked');
    $(this).addClass('unchecked');
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass('unchecked');
    $(this).addClass('checked');
  }
});
```

```css
.referent-R {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  content: 'R';
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.referent-R.checked {
  color: rgb(76, 10, 89);
}

.referent-R.unchecked {
  color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="referent-R" title="référent"></span>
```

Thanks a lot !!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery switch classes on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54765699/jquery-switch-classes-on-click)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:checked` selector only applies to radio buttons and checkboxes.

You can make the behaviour you require work in this case by setting the `checked` or `unchecked` class on the element by default then simply toggling those classes on click. Try this:

```js
$('.referent-R').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('checked unchecked');
});
```

```css
.referent-R {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  content: 'R';
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.referent-R.checked {
  color: rgb(76, 10, 89);
}

.referent-R.unchecked {
  color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="referent-R checked" title="référent">Foo</span>
```